# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: main_companyclass.FinancialYearEnd

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am running into the above-mentioned error when trying to run my app after creating a form that only updates 1 field.

What I am trying to achieve is as follows:

The user enters a client into the app and that saves it to the database, once that is done the client should be displayed on the checklist page where it will display some details about the client and show a checkbox ***(isdone_IT14)*** to say whether the clients' order has been completed.

The problem is that it doesn't seem that when the user ticks the checkbox and saves it, it doesn't seem like its updating that entry in the model.

I had created the below form to assist with that:

```
class CompanyIT14Form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CompanyClass
        fields= ['isdone_IT14']
```

But it is clearly not the correct solution. Does anyone know a better way to solve this error ?

Please see the below code:

**Models.py:**

```
class CompanyClass(models.Model):
    #Company Only Fields
    CompanyName = models.CharField(max_length=50 , blank=False)
    RefNo = models.CharField(max_length=50 , blank=False )
    FinancialYearEnd = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=False)

    #Contact Details
    ContactPerson = models.CharField( max_length=50, blank=False)
    EmailAddress = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)

    #Services
    IT14 = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    # CheckList
    isdone_IT14 = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return ( self.CompanyName)
```

**Forms.py:**

```
class CompanyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CompanyClass
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'FinancialYearEnd' : forms.SelectDateWidget,
        }

class CompanyIT14Form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CompanyClass
        fields= ['isdone_IT14']
```

**Views.py:**

```
class companyIT14(View):

    def get(self,request):
        it14s = CompanyClass.objects.filter(IT14 = True).order_by('CompanyName')
        form = CompanyIT14Form()
        content = {'it14s':it14s , 'form':form}
        return render(request, 'main/Checklists/companyIT14.html', content)

    def post(self,request):
        it14s = CompanyClass.objects.filter(IT14=True).order_by('CompanyName')
        form = CompanyIT14Form(request.POST)
        content = {'it14s': it14s, 'form': form}
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('companyIT14')
        else:
            print(form.errors)
            return render(request, 'main/checklistHome.html', content)
```

**Template.html:**

```
{% extends "main/base.html"%}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
{% block content %}
<body>
<br>
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <h1 class="h1" style="text-align: center">Companies IT14's</h1>

<table class="table table-hover table-dark"  style="width: 80%;text-align: center;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Company</th>
            <th scope="col">Ref No.</th>
            <th scope="col">Contact Person</th>
            <th scope="col">E-mail Address</th>
            <th scope="col">Completed?</th>
            <th scope="col">Save</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for x in it14s %}
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{ x.CompanyName }}</th>
            <th>{{ x.RefNo }}</th>
            <th>{{ x.ContactPerson }}</th>
            <th>{{ x.EmailAddress }}</th>
            <form class="form-group mt-4" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <th>{{ form.isdone_IT14  }}</th>
            <th><button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Save</button> </th>
            </form>
    {% endfor %}
</table>

    {% endif %}
</body>
{% endblock %}
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are obviously trying to `save` a form with `None` as value of `FinancialYearEnd` that has got `null=False` so it's forbidden. If the form is trying to save object with only `isdone_IT14` with value it might give `None` to all the rest and has to raise this error.

I think you may try to change to `null=True` for now and see what the form is actually changing in objects.